# Can OpenCV or PyTesseract recognize fonts

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract, python-tesseract

Using the below code I am able to read all text in an image:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread(r'/<path_to_image>/text.png')
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img))
```

What I want to know is does OpenCV or PyTesseract support text extraction based on font name? For example, if particular text is in Times New Roman and the rest of the text is Arial only extract the Times New Roman. Something like this:

```
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='font'))
```

Comment: Yes, tesseract supports that, but you would need to either generate tessdata by yourself or find it somewhere. Common tessdata files are trained using variety of fonts and it is not possible to specify font by design.

Comment: @DmitriiZ. Your statement is confusing. OP doesnt asks if he cant do recognition with fonts, but if tesseract can do recognition of fonts

Comment: @Martin oh I see, I got confused by `What I want to know is does OpenCV or PyTesseract support text extraction based on font name?`. My comment only answers that part. Regarding the second part - no, there is no way to only extract text based on its font, tesseract will try to extract text from everything you supply.

Answer (score 1):

Of course no. Tesseract hardly recognizes G from 6 and OpenCV is computer vision library.