Extract text from image using tessaract and opencv
screenshot.png:

modified_image.png: 
I am trying to extract text from an image but seems however I do it tessaract gives me some random values even though I think I have processed the image to a very good format. I am only after the white text and want to disregard the red text.
import cv2 as cv
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

image = cv.imread("screenshot.png", cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

ret, modified_image = cv.threshold(image, 120, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv.THRESH_OTSU)

modified_image= cv.resize(modified_image, None, fx=2, fy=2, interpolation=cv.INTER_CUBIC)

#cv.imshow("image", image)
#cv.imshow("modified_image", modified_image)
cv.imwrite("modified_image.png", modified_image)

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('modified_image.png'), config="--psm 6 --oem 3", lang="eng")

print(f'Text: {text}')

This will incorrectly print "CWS-1Y" instead of "CW9-1Y". From what I have understood the font in use is Shentox but seems like quite the task to train tessaract on it from what I could find online

@user24714692 All images are like that, the format of letters/digits can be different though (they come from a game)

more context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78450023/correctly-extract-text-from-image-using-tesseract-ocr

Send me your ISK and I will double it! Jokes aside, have you tried not resizing the image, or using different scale factors, or different interpolation, or higher threshold?

I'm out of idea for using Tesseract. Can't do better than this. Instead, you can clean, segment your images, and write grid algorithms to find these letters (character by char) with a much higher accuracy. (Fails to recognize between S and 9 which have similar patterns).

@GSazheniuk haha :) Yeah been trying different things for hours

possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56566267/can-opencv-or-pytesseract-recognize-fonts @AndreasEllsen

@AndreasEllsen I tried tesseract and it is working for me, even with psm 6. No idea why it is not working for you. Even with saving modified_image and then reading it is working. Have you tried not saving and then reading the image? which tesseract version do you have?

Tesseract, while being "good" is not the best.
For critical applications I tend to use EasyOCR so maybe give that a shot.
It's free and opensource as well.
Here's an example:
import easyocr
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en']) # this needs to run only once to load the model into memory



result = reader.readtext('chinese.jpg')
print(result)


I have tried it also with similar results so not optimal either


Read the docs: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc/blob/main/ImproveQuality.md
Adjust image according docs:

Resize image to meet optimal letter size
Invert image (dark letters on bright background
(optional) convert to grayscale (or binarize)




tesseract modified_image_based_on_docs.png - --psm 6
CW9-1Y

